# Gulp plugin for non-file processing tasks

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to write a gulp plugin for some experimental stuffs.

The plugin needs only to accept a callback, when its experiment is done, it fires the callback with true(experiment success) or false(experiment failure).

It has nothing to do with any of the files.

I could not find any plugin that do non-file processing.

My use case is whenever i am about to make a release of my project, i want to experiment some stuff, if the experiment fails, the release should get stop and terminated, otherwise let the release go out in production.

So how should i write such plugin.?

Of course a gulp plugin should return a stream (correct me if i am wrong). But in my case there is nothing like stream.

In file-processing, gulp plugin receives a set of files. When the last file processing done, task is also done and so gulp know to execute the next task. (correct me if i am wrong)

But in my case, in the plugin code, i won't have any promise/done callbacks. How do i let gulp know that my task is done?

How do i handle my case.?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way of doing this.

Here's an example:

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('MyTaskName', function(success) {
   var err;

   // Do whatever you want here

   // If you want to signal an error, define it like this
   err = new gutil.PluginError({
      plugin: 'MyTaskName',
      message: "<My Error Message>"
   });

   if (err) {
     // If something went wrong, throw an error
     throw err;
   }

   // Otherwise, all's good
   success();
}
```

Comment: Is this a part of gulpfile or code of plugin? Actually i am looking for code of plugin, not of gulp file.

Comment: you probably don't need a plugin for this, can you post your gulp file please?

Comment: I wrote this up as a plugin for you. Have a look at [gulp-vanilla](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-vanilla) Enjoy :)

Comment: nice to see plugin.. but i would like give more effort to search/create a better answer, if possible.. may be some other approach.

Comment: sure, let me know if you find something more convenient